# Prove that $\frac{\pi}{\phi^2}<\frac65 $

Tags: number-theory, inequality, pi, golden-ratio

How to prove that$$\frac{\pi}{\phi^2}<\frac{6}5 $$ from the definition of $\pi$ and $\phi$? ($\pi=4\int_{0}^1\sqrt{1-t^2}dt,\phi=\dfrac{\sqrt5+1}2.$)

Comment: From the definition of $\pi$ (which definition of $\pi$?), you can get the decimal expansion of $\pi$ to as many digits as you like, and that's one way to answer the question.

Comment: [What can I say?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*pi%2F%281%2Bsqrt%285%29%29%5E2+-+6%2F5) Speechless :O

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It we express $\pi$ and $\phi$ as simple continued fractions, it is known:
$$\pi = [3;7,15,1,292,1,1,,1,2,\ldots]
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\phi = [1;1,1,1\ldots].$$
The first few convergents of $\pi$ and $\phi$ are

$$3, \frac{22}{7}, \frac{333}{106}, \frac{355}{113}, \ldots
\quad\text{ and }\quad
1, \frac{2}{1}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{3} \ldots, \frac{F_k}{F_{k-1}} \ldots$$
where $F_k$ are the Fibonacci numbers. It is also known these convergents sandwich the values of $\pi$ and $\phi$ in alternate fashion.

$$3 < \frac{333}{106} < \pi < \frac{355}{113} < \frac{22}{7}$$
$$1 < \frac{3}{2} < \cdots < \frac{F_{2k}}{F_{2k-1}} < \phi < \frac{F_{2k+1}}{F_{2k}} < \cdots < \frac{5}{3} < \frac{2}{1}$$

In particular, $\pi < \frac{355}{113}$ and $
\frac{377}{233} = \frac{F_{14}}{F_{13}} = \frac{\phi^{14} - \phi^{-14}}{\phi^{13}+\phi^{-13}} < \phi
$, this implies

$$\frac{5\pi}{6\phi^2} < \frac{5\left(\frac{355}{113}\right)}{6\left(1+\left(\frac{377}{233}\right)\right)} = \frac{82715}{82716} < 1$$

Comment: OP wants to start from the definition of $\pi$ as a definite integral. How do you get to the continued fraction from there?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can't